# Need help splitting a string into multiple arrays in Visual basic

Tags: arrays, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am given this .txt file.

```
Left Behind,Lahaye,F,7,11.25
A Tale of Two Cities,Dickens,F,100,8.24
Hang a Thousand Trees with Ribbons,Rinaldi,F,30,16.79
```

That file is:
*Book Title*, *Author* ,*Fiction or Nonfiction*, *Stock* ,*Price*

I need to split those into multiple arrays, at least I feel like I do, I have this so far

```
    Private Sub frmInventory_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Populate array
    Dim temp() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("Books.txt")
    temp = Split(",")
    lstBooks.DataSource = temp.ToList
End Sub
```

which isn't doing the trick... obviously.

I just don't know how to make it put it into multiple arrays, such as book, etc. or maybe a 2 dimensional array.

Thanks for any help.

I have looked on many sites like this, but the only help they offer is splitting it in 2. 
http://patorjk.com/programming/tutorials/vbarrays.htm#splitfunction

Answer (score 2):

If the format is always so strict, you can do it manually with string.Split, otherwise i would suggest to use an existing library like [`FileHelpers`](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/), this [fast CSV parser](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader) or the VB.NET onboard [`TextFieldParser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx) class.

To answer your actual question, you can use an `File.ReadLines` and an `IEnumerable(Of String())`.

```
Dim lines As IEnumerable(Of String()) = 
         From line In IO.File.ReadLines("Books.txt")
         Select line.Split(","c)
```

If you want an array: `lines.ToArray()`, that will load all into memory(like [`File.ReadAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx)) whereas `File.ReadLines` streams the lines from the file and only if you ask for(f.e. via `Take(10)`).

**Edit**: If you want the most reusable approach, use a custom class with these properties and initialize it from the string():

```
Public Class Book
    Public Property Title As String
    Public Property Author As String
    ' and so on '
End Class

 Dim books = From line In System.IO.File.ReadLines("Books.txt")
             Let parts = line.Split(","c)
             Select New Book() With {
                .Title = parts(0),
                .Author = parts(1)
            }
```

You can use this for example in a `For Each` or as DataSource. Note that it is error-prone, the title probably contains also commas or the format is not always strict.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what you want to do with the data, its hard to help.
But i imagine your best bet would be to create a book class, with properties for Book Title, Author ,Price etc.

Create a list(of book), read the txt file line by line, splitting each line on commas, and creating a book instance with each resulting array, and add it to the list, like this hastily written example:

```
Public Class book
Property title As String
Property author As String
Property price As Double

Public Sub New(ByVal title As String, ByVal author As String, ByVal price As Double)
    _title = title
    _author = author
    _price = price
End Sub
End Class

Public Class Form1
Public booklist As List(Of book)
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)     Handles Button1.Click
    Dim bookfile As String() = IO.File.ReadAllLines("c:\file.txt")
    For Each line As String In bookfile
        Dim bookinfo As String() = line.Split(",")
        Dim abook As New book(bookinfo(0), bookinfo(1), bookinfo(2))
        booklist.Add(abook)
    Next
End Sub
End Class
```

If this is the kind of thing you would like to do, i will improve the above code as needed

Comment: I appreciate your answer! but basically all I'm trying to do with the data is use the arrays I get to make the data sortable, so I could say 

if author(1) is Lahaye then
Author(1) = ("Lahi") 

or something like that

That's why I'm trying to split it into multiple arrays

Comment: Ok, im finding it hard to understand what you want to achieve. Perhaps you could edit your question to give the big picture, because it still seems like you just want to sort the data, and a list(of object) seems to be the simplest option.